# Given a sequence $a_k \in\mathbb{R}_+$ find the periodicity of $\sum\limits_k \sin(a_kx) $

Tags: periodic-functions

I'm writing some code to visualize musical chords and I've hit a little snag with my math abilities.

**Given a sequence $a_k \in\mathbb{R}_+$ find the periodicity of the function**:

$$\sum\limits_k \sin(a_kx) $$

I really don't know what the method(s) for determining periodicity is(are). As a programmer I was considering opening wolfram endpoints and scraping the answers I needed from there **but that's no fun**. I appreciate your help and if you want to see what I'm building on I have a bit of code for this project posted here :: https://gist.github.com/Krewn/4c170d151afb1708220da25720d4890a

Comment: One gotcha: unless all of the $a_k$ are rational multiples of $a_1$ then the function won't _be_ periodic.  For instance, $\sin(x)+\sin(\sqrt{2}\cdot x)$ isn't a periodic function.  (This is part of why bells and drums and wood blocks seem to have somewhat less musical tones than e.g. strings.)

Comment: Yeah that occurred to me. I have some code for rationalizing floating point approximations but it doesn't really fit the problem because floating point representations of irrational numbers and repeating decimals are in themselves rational approximations... : (
https://gist.github.com/Krewn/e569fd90ebae6a87d102b84bdfc83b08

Comment: What do you mean by "find the periodicity"? Do you want to determine **if** the function is periodic? (I.e. answer is $0$ or $1$)? Or do you want to find the period of a periodic function?

Comment: Both... If a function is periodic I would like to know the fundamental period.

Answer (score 1):

This problem relates to digital signal processing (DSP). For serious acquaintance with the theme can be recommended the book of [Blahut](http://This%20problem%20relates%20to%20digital%20signal%20processing.%20For%20serious%20acquaintance%20with%20the%20theme%20of%20the%20book%20can%20be%20recommended%20Blahut)

Methods for this problem solving are divided into linear (based on FFT) and non-linear (based on autoregressive models). Typical for linear methods are using of FFT algorythm with weighted Hamming window. Linear model presents signal as sum of known fixed harmonics with the constant step, and it's easy to realization.
The only drawback of the method is the limited accuracy of the frequency measurement.

But if you want to discover the frequency beyond the scale of the FFT, then the best choice becomes Durbin method based on AR model. I already wrote about this method on the [Russian site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95184/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B8%D0%BD/468364#468364), where you can find texts of programs. Here I give the translation of the article.

One of the best forecasting methods - autoregressive. In any case, the periodic bursts catch it.

**Signal Model**

The method - a model of autoregression (AR) of order $k$ for sample $i=0,1,\dots, n-1:$
$$x_i + f_0x_{i-1} + f_1x_{i-2} + f_2x_{i-3} + \dots + f_{k-1}x_{i-k} = 0,$$ 
where $i = k, k+1,\dots, n-1.$

The desired frequencies are the roots of the characteristic equation
$$1+f_0\omega+f_1\omega^2+f_2\omega^3+\dot+f_{k-1}\omega^{k}=0.$$
The order of the model should correspond approximately to the complexity of signal.

**Toeplitz symmetry**

According to the method of least squares, the discrepancy
$$\varepsilon = \left<(x_i + f_0x_{i-1} + f_1x_{i-2} + f_2x_{i-3} + ... + f_kx_{i-k})^2\right>_{i=k\dots n-1}$$
should be minimized.
For this, should equate to zero the partial derivatives by the AR coefficients $f_s$ for $s = 0\dots k-1$.
This leads to the following system of equations special:

\begin{cases}
a_0f_0 + a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + ... + a_{k-2}f_{k-2} + a_{k-1}f_{k-1} = -a_1,\\
a_1f_0 + a_0f_1 + a_1f_2 + ... + a_{k-3}f_{k-2} + a_{k-2}f_{k-1} = -a_2,\\
a_2f_0 + a_1f_1 + a_0f_2 + ... + a_{k-4}f_{k-2} + a_{k-3}f_{k-1} = -a_3,\\
\dots\\
a_{k-2}f_0 + a_{k-3}f_1 + a_{k-4}f_2 + ... + a_0f_{k-2} + a_1f_{k-1} = -a_{k-1},\\
a_{k-1}f_0 + a_{k-2}f_1 + a_{k-3}f_2 + ... + a_1f_{k-2} + a_0f_{k-1} = -a_k,
\end{cases}
where $a$ is the autocorrelation function (ACF).

The first feature is the form of LHS matrix with the same coefficients on the main diagonal and that all the coefficients on the diagonal, equidistant from the main. Matrix with the symmetry of this type are called Toeplitz, and Levinson algorithm is applicable to them.

The second feature - that the free column members formed of the same elements of the matrix $a$, and the algorithm of Levinson-Durbin is applicable to such a system.

The third feature is in fact that considering matrix is Toeplitz ​​only approximate. For example, for a second-order model, the exact form of the equations is:
$$\begin{cases}
\left<x_{i-1}^2\right>f_0 + \left<x_{i-1}x_{i-2}\right>f_1 = \left<x_ix_{i-1}\right>\\
\left<x_{i-1}x_{i-2}\right>f_0 + \left<x_{i-2}^2\right>f_1 = \left<x_ix_{i-2}\right>,
\end{cases}$$
where $i$ is the index of the amount of each type of $\left<u_i\right>$ runs from $2$ to the maximum.

It is not difficult to note that:

$1)$ the items of the main diagonal correspond to element zero autocorrelation function samples for computation are shifted by one element.
$2)$ the items on the secondary diagonal and the first item in the column of free terms correspond to the first element of the autocorrelation function, within diagonal elements are equal, and sample for free member moved toward them.

This can lead to unexpected effects for sequences with a strong increasing (decreasing) trend.

So, for the sample of the first $10$ members of the Fibonacci sequence
$x_i = \{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55\}$
we obtain the system of equations in form
$$\begin{cases}
1869f_0 + 1155f_1 = - 3024,\\
1155f_0 + 714f_1 = - 1869
\end{cases}$$
with the correct solution $f_0 = -1,\ f_1 = -1,$ but the expected Toeplitz symmetry of the problem doesn't exist.
The use of the ACF system gives
$$\begin{cases}
4893f_0 + 3024f_1 = - 3024,\\
3024f_0 + 4893f_1 = - 1869,
\end{cases}$$
using of which in this case is inappropriate. The main method of dealing with these effects - centering of the sample. But the main moment is checking the possibility of a serious simplification of the model for using of Durbin algorithm.

**Durbin algorithm**

The Durbin idea is to search for a solution as the matrix of dimension $n+1$ in the form of:
$$\left(f'_0, f'_1,\dots, f'_{n-1}, f'_n\right) = \left(f_0, f_1, ..., f_{n-1}, 0\right) + \beta\left(f_{n-1},f_{n-2},\dots,f_0,1\right).$$
Indeed, the substitution of this solution in a matrix of dimension $n+1,$ taking into account the dimension $n,$ gives the system:
$$\begin{cases}
-a_1 - \beta a_n + a_n\beta = -a_1,\\
-a_2 - \beta a_{n-1} + a_{n-1}\beta = -a_2,\\
\dots\\
-a_{n-1} - \beta a_1 + a_1\beta = -a_n,\\
a_nf_0 + a_{n-1}f_1 + a_{n-2}f_2 + ... + a_2f_{n-2} + a_1f_{n-1}\\ + \beta (a_nf_{n-1} + a_{n-1}f_{n-2} + a_{n-2}f_{n-3} + ... + a_2f_1 + a_1f_0 + a_0) = -a_{n+1}.
\end{cases}$$
$N$ the first equations of the system are satisfied for any value of $\beta$, the latter - at
$$\beta = - \dfrac{a_{n+1} + a_nf_0 + a_{n-1}f_1 + a_{n-2}f_2 +\dots+ a_2f_{n-2} + a_1f_{n-1}}{a_nf_{n-1} + a_{n-1}f_{n-2} + a_{n-2}f_{n-3} + \dots + a_2f_1 + a_1f_0 + a_0}.$$

*durbin()* function returns an array of AR vectors for a total of $n$ range.
For $n=1\ f = -\dfrac{a_1}{a_0},$ the following vectors of coefficients are calculated recursively (first $\beta$, and then $f$).

**Software implementation**

The program in PHP has the following features:

Centering array $center()$.
The scalar product of the vectors of the second vector shifted $scalar\_prod()$.
The output of the array with a text commentary $print\_array()$.
The output of the system of linear equations of the second order and its solutions $print\_s()$.
The calculation of the autocorrelation function (ACF) $acf().$
Compare accurate and Toeplitz second order systems and solutions for a given sample $compare\_s().$
Durbin algorithm for solving the system of equations of a special form $durbin()$.
Test Durbin algorithm $test\_durbin()$.

**Results**

The program showed high efficiency in a limited (sine) sample with a large volume of raw data.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it will take me some time to chew through but it looks like there is some nice stuff in here. +1

Comment: @kpie You are welcome!

Comment: @kpie If you want to use my 16 years of professional experience in DSP, then drop the forward links to new questions here

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ i.e. rational.

Numbers in a computer can be represented as rationals due to finite precision.

Let $\displaystyle a_k = \frac{n_k}{d_k}$ with $\gcd(n_k,d_k) = 1$

You want $a_kx = 2 \pi I_k$ where $I_k$ is an integer.

This will occur for all $\sin(a_kx)$ for any integer multiple of:

$$x = 2 \pi \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{N} d_{k}$$

$x$ will cancel out the denominator $d_k$ of all $\sin(a_k x)$.

No $d_k$ needs to be repeated so use the least common multiple $LCM$

If all $n_k$ are divisible by $2$ then it can be divided out. Any common divisor can be cancelled.

$$Period = \frac{2\pi \, LCM(d_1,\dots ,d_N)}{gcd(n_1,\dots,n_N)} $$